# Error when attempting to read from a UDP socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp, python-3.4

I create a UDP socket and send data to an address that is not listening. The next time I attempt to receive data, it fails with the error `[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. As an example, this code will error on the last line. Why and how can I fix it?

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto(bytes("A", 'utf-8'), ("127.0.0.1", 5000))
s.recvfrom(128)
```

Comment: Fix it? Have you considered sending to an address that *is* listening? You caused an error, you got an error. What's to fix?

Answer (score 1):

> I create a UDP socket and send data **to an address that is not listening**

The answer is in the question. Just make sure that there is a server side logic to send you back data.
Otherwise the OS will send back to your app an ICMP message saying that there is nothing listening on that port, which will trigger the [WinError 10054] that you are reporting. BTW, UDP being in essence a connection-less protocol, the error message cannot be accurate.